# Bad request 400 when debug = False

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-400, cookiecutter

I have a problem with a "Bad Request 400" (the production server) when I have set debug = false. I use cookiecutter and Django 1.8.
I set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` - without any result.

In the logs I have a message:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'myaddress.here'. You may need to add 'myaddress.here' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I tried the code that is placed in the documentation django, also without success:

```
'handlers': {
    'null': {
        'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*','yourdomain.com','www.yourdomain.com','123.456.78.91']?

Comment: Yes, I had the same result.

Comment: try this ['127.0.0.1','localhost','www.domain.com','domain.com']

Comment: did you restarted production server ?

Comment: Yes of course.
Is the problem may be to use a cookie cutter?